# Find arguments for an EXE and make it run programmatically

Tags: command-line, automation, exe

Ten years ago, a previous developer of my company has created a software that let a user accomplish some repetitive tasks faster.
That developer splitted up the software in several exe files, based on specific functions, so we have a "main.exe" file that runs other exe (let's say "tasA.exe", "taskB.exe" and so on) depending on which task the user want to do.

Now my company would like to go further and automate some of that tasks, without the requirement of human action, and planned to replace one by one the "taskX.exe" files. Meanwhile, the "taskX.exe" files should be scheduled and runned in unattended mode, without have to pass from "main.exe", until the new version will be released.

Unfortunately, the company has no more the source code and the previous developer has not included any hint so calling the exe with "/?" "--help" has no effect: the exe simply exits, does not crash nor print anything, neither a log. Even its creator doesn't remember the exact params that could let it run in "unattended" mode, but he is certain that it is definitely possible.

The only thing I know, based on the dll surrounding the file, is that the exe was built with Python and QT library and when running it show a UI that let the user accomplish some operations.

Is there a way to know such arguments?

Can the arguments be desumed when the exe is running in attended mode?

Is there anything that I could try, maybe create a software that simulate the human action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to reverse engineer it.

1. Extract the bytecode from the exe
2. Use a python decompiler to translate bytecode back to python

Comment: Thank for your suggestions. Could you please be more specific? Is there a tool I can use for step 1?

Comment: It depends on what program was used to generate the exe. A google search reveals quite a lot tools so maybe your lucky. If none of them work you'll have to use something like ghidra to unpack/extract by hand.